# Need help for communication between server database and android app

Tags: android, json, networking, webserver, client-server

I am developing an Android based app that does both the things:

1. Add data to the server.
2. Fetch data from the server.

Data consists of a multimedia file which can be either:

1. Picture + Some info about Picture
2. Video + Some info about Video
3. Simple Text + Some info about the text

In the above, info consists of things like Latitude, longitude, user name etc.

I want to know as to how to achieve the desired ?

I have been suggested to use JSON based object and pass it to the android app.
I know how to parse the JSON object but have no idea about things like:

1. How does the android app running on mobile device requests for JSON object ? (meaning which URL to ask)
2. How to pass the multimedia object (Picture/Video) from server to App in form of JSON object?
3. How to send data from android app running of android based phone to the server ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your questions;

1. You need to have a service running on the server. Android parses the json and sends it to this service. So you will need to use the URL of your service.
2. You can pass multimedia objects to the service by converting it to a Byte or Base64String.'
3. With regards to how to parse the json and send it to the server, I'd recommend you look at [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). This is one of the most commonly used libraries when working with JSON

Look into this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for a more indepth tutorial on Json parsing
*Note: While JSON is the recommended way to pass objects to and from the server, wsdl is another option you can use.*

Comment: How to run the service on the server, which listens for requests by android app ? Also how will the Android app make request to the server?  (I will be able to send JSON object AFTER a request is made, but HOW to make the request ? )

Comment: Well you need to write a service using java, php or your favorite web framework. If you are using php, you need to have an apache server running with your php there. The php service will have to read your input and parse a json output. And in android you will have to provide the URL for the php service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by converting to Base64String. Check [this link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/)